# DotNet: Static variables in DLL

Tags: c#, .net, c, dll, static

I am working on a Dot Net project, which includes a DLL. This DLL uses a .lib (C code). Unfortunately, there are many static variables in this .lib. The Problem I have here:

If two users perform a search at the same time, I get an error, because they both access the .lib, one changes something while to other tries to read data.

The obvious solution, would be to lock the access, but I really don't want to do that, because that slows the search process down drastically. I would rather try to make a DLL from the lib, but I don't know if this would solve the problem, as I don't know if the static variables will then be stored separately, or if both search processes will access the same variables.

Does anyone have experience with this? Because it will take quite an amount of time to do this, and I'd like to know if it works before I start to do this.

I hope everything is understandable, as English is not my first language, and my programming skills are pretty basic.

Comment: You *should* avoid excessive use of *static* fields. Try to change *Type* design.

Comment: The problem is, that the C code is full of statics, it would take way too long to change everything. The only fast alternative I see atm, is trying this DLL "trick".

Comment: @Stefan: define a new type in a new assembly which has an access to that C code (and only it), in other words a wrapper for it. Adn from whithin that type, manage esclusive access to C resources in way you want. So if you want to call some C function, you have to use that type, and if you will call something in the middel of execution, the same type will block you, raise an exception, show message.. whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, there is no way you are going to be able to simulataniously edit the data while you are reading from it using the existing classes within this .dll. Clearly this will just not work, no matter what fancy stuff you are doing.

What you could do is create a [Thunking Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk_%28functional_programming%29). This will be a type of wrapper class that will be called instead of the .dll. This class will handle concurrent I/O requests by holding a local copy of the data for reads, and allowing smultanious edits to the real data, updating the local copy when these manipulations are finished (with appropriate temporary locking etc.). There may be other standard ways of doing this that I not aware of, but this is how I would start.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The idea would be, that every user will have his own version of the DLL running. Now the problem is, I dont know if in Dot Net, the static variables will be shared amongst the users, or not. But thank you for the link, I will look into it, sounds interesting!

Comment: @Stefan static variables in `.NET Framework` are shared amongs all users of application which this variables are part of. If you will make 1 extra layer for exposing this data it's may help but I'm not sure about it.